# How to properly uninstall pyenv on linux?

Tags: python, bash, pyenv

I have installed `pyenv` on a raspberry pi but now I want to uninstall it.

I already ran the command `rm -rf $(pyenv root)` but now it says to delete lines from my "shell startup configuration". What does it mean? I found this lines in my `.bash_profile` files:

```sh
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval"$(pyenv init-)"
fi
```

And in `.bashrc` file at the end there is:

```sh
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

Should I only delete (or comment with `#`) the ones from `.bash_profile`? Or maybe from both files?

Comment: @oguzismail Following installation guide on thei github readme (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) tho I also had to install some libs that from here (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems). I followed insructions for Ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete all 5 lines from both files. Then make sure that in your `.bash_profile` it tells `.bashrc` to load

Comment: I also removed the lines updating PATH in `.profile`